# How to get remaining days for certain birthday?

Tags: javascript, calculator

When I'm calculating my age, the code below showing "*xxx days left for your next birthday*". But I want to know, how many days left for my **certain birthday**. (i.e: I want to know how many days left for my 30th birthday. The result should be like this "*xxx days left for your 30th birthday*" instead of next birthday.)
What change I need to do?

```js
function wr_document() {
  var w = new Date();
  var s_d = w.getDate();
  var s_m = w.getMonth() + 1;
  var s_y = w.getFullYear();


  document.cir.len11.value = s_d;
  document.cir.len12.value = s_m;
  document.cir.len13.value = s_y;
}

function isNum(arg) {
  var args = arg;
  if (args == "" || args == null || args.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  args = args.toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if ((args.substring(i, i + 1) < "0" || args.substring(i, i + 1) > "9") && args.substring(i, i + 1) != ".") {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function checkday(aa) {
  var val = aa.value;
  var valc = val.substring(0, 1);
  if (val.length > 0 && val.length < 3) {
    if (!isNum(val) || val == 0) {
      aa.value = "";
    } else if (val < 1 || val > 31) {
      aa.value = valc;
    }
  } else if (val.length > 2) {
    val = val.substring(0, 2);
    aa.value = val;
  }
}

function checkmon(aa) {
  var val = aa.value;
  var valc = val.substring(0, 1);
  if (val.length > 0 && val.length < 3) {
    if (!isNum(val) || val == 0) {
      aa.value = "";
    } else if (val < 1 || val > 12) {
      aa.value = valc;
    }
  } else if (val.length > 2) {
    val = val.substring(0, 2);
    aa.value = val;
  }
}

function checkyear(aa) {
  var val = aa.value;
  var valc = val.substring(0, (val.length - 1));
  if (val.length > 0 && val.length < 7) {
    if (!isNum(val) || val == 0) {
      aa.value = valc;
    } else if (val < 1 || val > 275759) {
      aa.value = "";
    }
  } else if (val.length > 4) {
    aa.value = valc;
  }
}

function checkleapyear(datea) {
  if (datea.getYear() % 4 == 0) {
    if (datea.getYear() % 10 != 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if (datea.getYear() % 400 == 0)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function DaysInMonth(Y, M) {
  with(new Date(Y, M, 1, 12)) {
    setDate(0);
    return getDate();
  }
}

function datediff(date1, date2) {
  var y1 = date1.getFullYear(),
    m1 = date1.getMonth(),
    d1 = date1.getDate(),
    y2 = date2.getFullYear(),
    m2 = date2.getMonth(),
    d2 = date2.getDate();
  if (d1 < d2) {
    m1--;
    d1 += DaysInMonth(y2, m2);
  }
  if (m1 < m2) {
    y1--;
    m1 += 12;
  }
  return [y1 - y2, m1 - m2, d1 - d2];
}

function calage() {
  var curday = document.cir.len11.value;
  var curmon = document.cir.len12.value;
  var curyear = document.cir.len13.value;
  var calday = document.cir.len21.value;
  var calmon = document.cir.len22.value;
  var calyear = document.cir.len23.value;
  if (curday == "" || curmon == "" || curyear == "" || calday == "" || calmon == "" || calyear == "") {
    alert("Please fill all the values and click 'Go'");
  } else if (curday == calday && curmon == calmon && curyear == calyear) {
    alert("Today your birthday & Your age is 0 years old")
  } else {
    var curd = new Date(curyear, curmon - 1, curday);
    var cald = new Date(calyear, calmon - 1, calday);
    var diff = Date.UTC(curyear, curmon, curday, 0, 0, 0) -
      Date.UTC(calyear, calmon, calday, 0, 0, 0);
    var dife = datediff(curd, cald);
    document.cir.val.value = dife[0] + " years, " + dife[1] + " months, and " + dife[2] + " days";
    var secleft = diff / 1000 / 60;
    document.cir.val3.value = secleft + " minutes since your birth";
    var hrsleft = secleft / 60;
    document.cir.val2.value = hrsleft + " hours since your birth";
    var daysleft = hrsleft / 24;
    document.cir.val1.value = daysleft + " days since your birth";
    //alert(""+parseInt(calyear)+"--"+dife[0]+"--"+1);
    var as = parseInt(calyear) + dife[0] + 1;
    var diff = Date.UTC(as, calmon, calday, 0, 0, 0) -
      Date.UTC(curyear, curmon, curday, 0, 0, 0);
    var datee = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    document.cir.val4.value = datee + " days left for your next birthday";
  }
}

function color(test) {
  for (var j = 7; j < 12; j++) {
    var myI = document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(j);
    //myI.setAttribute("style",ch);
    myI.style.backgroundColor = test;
  }
}

function color1(test) {
  var myI = document.getElementsByTagName("table").item(0);
  //myI.setAttribute("style",ch);
  myI.style.backgroundColor = test;
}
```

```css
.cal-container {
  width: 540px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}

#age-calculator {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.calc {
  border-color: #AAAAAA #999999 #929292 #AAAAAA;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 2px 2px 1px;
  padding: 2px 30px 3px;
  height: 27px;
}

.calc:active {
  border-color: #AAAAAA #999999 #929292 #AAAAAA;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<title>Age calculator </title>

<body onload="wr_document()">
  <div class="cal-container">
    <div id="calculator-container">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%px;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">
              <h1 style="padding-top: 10px;">
                Age Calculator</h1>
              <div class="descalign">
                <span>Calculate your age in days, years, minutes, seconds. Know how many days are left for your next birthday.</span><br /><br />
              </div>
              <div id="age-calculator">
                <table bgcolor="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" style="width: 100%px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2">
                        <table class="result" style="height: 100%px; width: 100%px;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <form name="cir">
                                  <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                          <br /> Today's Date is:
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                          Date -
                                          <input class="innerc resform" name="len11" onkeyup="checkday(this)" size="2" type="text" value="" /> Month -
                                          <input class="innerc resform" name="len12" onkeyup="checkmon(this)" size="2" type="text" value="" /> Year -
                                          <input class="innerc resform" name="len13" onkeyup="checkyear(this)" size="4" type="text" value="" />
                                          <br />
                                          <br />
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"> Enter Your Date of Birth : </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                          Date -
                                          <input class="innerc resform" name="len21" onkeyup="checkday(this)" size="2" type="text" /> Month -
                                          <input class="innerc resform" name="len22" onkeyup="checkmon(this)" size="2" type="text" /> Year -
                                          <input class="innerc resform" name="len23" onkeyup="checkyear(this)" size="4" type="text" />
                                          <br />
                                          <br />
                                          <input class="calc" name="but" onclick="calage()" type="button" value=" Go " />
                                          <br />
                                          <br />
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" class="form" width="30%">
                                          <b> </b>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                  <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>
                                          <b> Your Age is </b>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          <input class="resform" name="val" readonly="" size="36" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>
                                          <b> Your Age in Days </b>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          <input class="resform" name="val1" readonly="" size="36" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>
                                          <b> Your Age in Hours </b>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          <input class="resform" name="val2" readonly="" size="36" type="text" /> (Approximate)
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="form">
                                          <b> Your Age in Minutes </b>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          <input class="resform" name="val3" readonly="" size="36" type="text" /> (Approximate)
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td> </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>
                                          <input class="innerc resform" name="val4" readonly="" size="36" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </form>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br />
                      </td>
                      <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right" colspan="2"> </td>
                      <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <br />
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! On this platform, you are expected to show some effort of your own: what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What errors are you getting? Please don't just paste some code you found on the internet and expect us to modify it for you to do what you want. Read [ask]

Comment: Thank you. I think here should be change, but don't what change. **var as = parseInt(calyear)+dife[0]+1;
var diff = Date.UTC(as,calmon,calday,0,0,0)
- Date.UTC(curyear,curmon,curday,0,0,0);
var datee = diff/1000/60/60/24;
document.cir.val4.value=datee+" days left for your next birthday";**

Comment: Please indent (format) your code

Comment: I would advice using momentJS

Answer (score 0):

Not clear about purpose of your whole code, but based on your question following script may help you.

```js
// Let below variables store your birth date
var day = 13;
var month = 03;
var year = 1993;
var x = 30; // Finding 30th birthday
var xthBirthday = new Date((year + x), (month - 1), day); // As month starts with 0
var timeForXthBirthday = xthBirthday.getTime() - Date.now();
var noOfDaysForXthBirthday = Math.ceil(timeForXthBirthday / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); // No. of days left for your xth birthday
document.write(noOfDaysForXthBirthday+" days left for your "+x+"<sup>th</sup> birthday.");
```

Hope this helps.